# Sql server sum(Case) convert to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Sum how many items were used over a period of time in two locations, but I'm stuck on a controller

SQL query:

```
select ITEMID,
       ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_TYPE,
       sum(case when PROVIDERID = 'PR000118' then QUANTITY else 0 end) as EAST,
       sum(case when PROVIDERID = 'PR000124' then QUANTITY else 0 end) as WEST,
       sum(QUANTITY) as TOTAL
from V_ITEMUSAGE 
where DATETIME >= '2021-03-01' and DATETIME <= '2021-03-31' and ITEM_TYPE like '%%'
group by ITEMID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_TYPE
order by TOTAL desc
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace HMO.viewmodel
{
    public class Itemusageviewmodel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ITEMTYPE> ITEMTYPEs{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<V_ITEMUSAGE> V_ITEMUSAGEs{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Itemusage (DateTime STARTDATE, DateTime ENDDATE, String TYPE)
{
    var table = new Itemusageviewmodel
    {
        ITEMTYPEs = db.ITEMTYPE.tolist(),
        V_ITEMUSAGEs = db.V_ITEMUSAGE
                       .Where(x => m.DATETIME >= STARTDATE && x.DATETIME <= ENDDATE  && x.ITEM_TYPE.Contains(TYPE))
                       //(I don't know what code I should use here)//
    };
    return View(table);
}
```

I want the result `V_ITEMUSAGEs` from Controller to be the same as the result of the SQL query, How I write The code for `V_ITEMUSAGEs`?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried GroupBy? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby

Comment: You have SQL that does what you need; why not just *use that SQL*? You don't have to convert everything to LINQ, and not everything *can* be expressed as LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I lack experience in the C # programming language because it's only been 1 month since I started it.

Comment: @MarcGravell if just use that SQL query, how to implement it? because for C# I only know using LINQ for select all and where condition. if you can explain it I helped

Comment: @SDG assuming that `db` here is Entity Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
b.V_ITEMUSAGE
 .Where(x => m.DATETIME >= STARTDATE && x.DATETIME <= ENDDATE  && x.ITEM_TYPE.Contains(TYPE))
 .GroupBy(x => new { x.ITEMID, x.ITEM_NAME, x.ITEM_TYPE })
 .Select(x => new ItemUsageViewModel {
       ItemId = x.Key.ITEMID,
       ItemName = x.Key.ITEM_Name,
       ItemType = x.Key.ITEM_TYPE,
       East = x.Where(it => it.PROVIDERID == 'PR000118').Sum(it => it.QUANTITY),
       West = x.Where(it => it.PROVIDERID == 'PR000124').Sum(it => it.QUANTITY),
       Total = x.Sum(it => it.QUANTITY)
  })
```

Where `ItemUsageViewModel`  is a custom DTO view model defined by you that should look something like

```
public ItemUsageViewModel  
{
    public int ItemId {get; set;}
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
    public string ItemType {get; set;}
    public int East {get; set;}
    public int West {get; set;}
    public int Total {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but the error says
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
on East, West, and Total

Comment: You should just change the `int` property types from the model above to `decimal`. I said that the DTO should be something like this, not exactly like this. What should the property types be exactly depends on your cDB column types. You did not provide the schema table for `V_ITEMUSAGE ` or for `ITEMTYPE` after all